# Negative number raised to a fractional power

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have a very trivial question about complex analysis. I have the number $(-3)^\frac{2}{3}$. However I am not sure if this is a complex number or not since I would assume the -3 is first squared and then we take the cubic root which is perfectly valid. Is that wrong?

The actual function itself I have to consider is:

$f(x)=(x-3)(x+2)^\frac{2}{3}$. If I plot it by using my calculator to check points, all values below $x=-2$ are real numbers but if I plot this on Mathematica or Wolfram Alpha for instance, I get that for all values below $x=-2$, the function is complex.

I'm not really sure what to trust. Is $f(x)$ complex for all $x<2$ or is it real?

Comment: The identity $a^{bc} = (a^b)^c$ doesn't hold in general when $a<0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a standard problem which, for your needs, has been fixed in Mathematica by function $CubeRoot[x]$ which returns the real-valued cube root of $x$ (see [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CubeRoot.html) and [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubeRoot.html)).

Answer (score 1):

There isn't just *one* answer since $f(z)=z^{\frac{2}{3}}$ is a multi-valued function. But one of these answers is real, though.